# View exit criteria of running version - Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

How can I see the exit criteria for a running journey? The exit criteria button is greyed out for the running version.

Pretty sure I currently have criteria set to EXIT IF status = instructed but a customer who meets that criteria has just received an email when they should have been ejected!

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in a journey, the 'Exit Criteria' or 'Goal' are not greyed out if they are configured. If its greyed out I would say it's not configured.

[image: Exit Criteria]